# How does the limit() option work in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, limit

Let say you have a collection of 10,000 documents and I make a find query with a the option limit(50). How will mongoDb choose which 50 documents to return.

Will it auto-sort them(maybe by their creation date) or not?

Will the query return the same documents every time it is called? How does the limit option work in mongodb?

Does mongoDB limit the documents after they are returned or as it queries them. Meaning will mongoDB query all documents the limit the results to 50 documents or will it query the 50 documents only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 50 documents of the *result set* will be returned.

If you do not sort the documents (or if the order is not well-defined, such as sorting by a field with values that occur multiple times in the result set), the order may change from one execution to the next.

> Will it auto-sort them(maybe by their creation date) or not?

No.

> Will the query return the same documents every time it is called?

The query may produce the same results for a while and then start producing different results if, for example, another document is inserted into the collection.

> Meaning will mongoDB query all documents the limit the results to 50 documents or will it query the 50 documents only?

Depends on the query. If an index is used, only the needed documents will be read from the storage engine. If a sort stage is used in the query execution, all documents will be read from storage, sorted, then the required number will be returned and the rest discarded.